# create additional oracle 11g database in linux

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, linux, database-recommendation

I have already created a database XE on my linux desktop.Please find the below information about the database.

> ORACLE_SID=XE
>
> ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
>
> ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe

I have to create another database,eg: database name is DB1. My question is how i can set ORACLE_HOME for DB1 and other parameters in pfile ?

Also i can avoid the error

```
ORA-45301: XE Edition single instance violation error
```

Answer (score 2):

[Oracle Database XE Installation and Execution Restrictions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18802/toc.htm#BEIEJGGF)

> Only one installation of Oracle Database XE can be performed on a
>   single computer. This does not affect any existing installation or new
>   installations of Oracle Database 11g Standard Edition, Oracle Database
>   11g Standard Edition One, or Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition.
>   In addition, **users can run only one instance of the Oracle Database XE
>   database on each individual computer.** **To run more than one Oracle
>   Database server instance or install more than one copy of the database
>   software, upgrade to Oracle Database 11g Standard Edition, Oracle
>   Database 11g Standard Edition One, or Oracle Database 11g Enterprise
>   Edition.**

Comment: how to identify installed database is express or standard edition?

Comment: It is Express Edition. Other editions do not throw that error.

Comment: i want to install 11g database on linux. let me know how to install the Oracle 11gR2 on linux (Ubuntu).

Comment: @azardin Ubuntu is not supported by Oracle. You should install Oracle Linux in a virtual machine and install Oracle database on that. Yes, it is possible to install on Ubuntu with some workarounds, but I would not go that way.